# why phantomjs is not working with splinter python?

Tags: python, splinter

I want to login in LinkedIn via phantom js browser. I am using splinter for this. splinter code is working correctly when it is running in chrome,Firefox browser. but if i change the browser to phantom js it showing me some error please tell me how to solve this problem.
without phantom js browser:
from splinter import Browser

```
with Browser() as browser:
    # Visit URL
    URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/"
    browser.visit(URL)
    browser.fill('session_key', 'abc123@gmail.com')
    print("your email id entered correctly") 

It works perfectly
with phantomjs browser:
from splinter import Browser
with Browser('phantomjs') as browser:
    # Visit URL
    URL = "https://www.linkedin.com/"
    browser.visit(URL)
    browser.fill('session_key', 'abc123@gmail.com')
    print("your email id entered correctly")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sampleFile.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser.fill('session_key', 'abc123@gmail.com')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 413, in fill
    field = self.find_by_name(name).first
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 53, in first
    return self[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    self.find_by, self.query))
splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found with name "session_key"
```